# Using the Friendly ID gem with Rails, how do you regenerate the slug field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, seo, friendly-id

I'm building a rails app that hosts games. Games belong to categories and thus each category can have many games.

I'm using the Friendly_id gem to generate URL slugs and have the following setup:

Category.rb

```
 class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name_and_games, use: [:slugged]

  has_many :games

  def name_and_games
    "#{name}-games"
  end
end
```

Games_Controller.rb

```
...
      def category
    @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.all
    @games = @category.games.page(params[:page])

    render 'games/index'
  end
...
```

Routes.rb

```
get ':friendly_id', to: "games#category", as: :category
```

Category_View.html.erb

```
<% categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= link_to category_path(category) do %>
    <span><%= pluralize(category.name.capitalize, "Game") %> (<%= category.games.count %>)</span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that when I use Friendly_id's slugged module, Rails is generating my urls WITHOUT the "-games" suffix so I end up with URLS like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/action
http://localhost:3000/adventure
```

Is there some way to have rails keep the "-games" in my URLs and have it all play nicely such that the "-games" are dropped when it comes time for processing in the model?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like the has_permalinks gem does a better job of solving this scenario than Friendly_id does. However, it'd be nice to get this working with Friendly_id as it seems to be the better supported option and it also has a good bit more functionality that I'd love to leverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue wasn't that Friendly_id wouldn't make the update but that the slug was not getting refreshed.

I had to drop into the Rails console and manually set the "slug" column to nil for each category. Once I did this, Friendly_id reset the "slug" column to reflect my additional text.

Answer (score 4):

So it's:

```
User.find_each{ |i| i.slug = nil; i.save!; }
```